# How do I get xbindkeys to separate its modifiers from xte's?

Tags: xbindkeys, xte

When I do such as this in `.xbindkeysrc`

```
"xte 'keydown Control_L' 'key W' 'keyup Control_L'"
    Shift + b:9
```

it performs the action of ctrl+shift+w instead of just the ctrl+w I expected. Any idea how to fix this? Adding `+ Release` to the second line doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xte` uses the XTest Extension, and just adds your requests to the current modifier state, rather than trying to start from some base state. Other tools such as `xdotool` provide a `--clearmodifiers` option, for example, to ensure you will get exactly what you want.

Since `xbindkeys` notices your request when the modifier state is with `Shift_L` or `Shift_R` pressed, this is the state `xte` works from. You should be able to emulate a shift-up to cancel this in `xte` by starting with `keyup Shift_L`, and perhaps also `Shift_R`. The real shift-up later will be ignored, or you could restore the shift state to what it was at the end of your `xte` actions, to avoid the need to press the shift key again, but that is for you to choose.